# HP p400i - 512MB RAID Controller card

Tags: raid, hardware, hp

Anyone know if the HP p400i raid controller can support multiple arrays? Say if I wanted a raid 0 with 2x146GB drives, and 3x300GB drives in a raid 5, both on the same card?

Also, is it possible to add drives to the raid 5 later down the road and expand out the partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both questions: **yes** is the answer.

You can create multiple logical drives on the same controller (page 8), and you can also expand your RAID5, providing you have both a Battery Backup Unit and Cache memory installed (page 16).

Reference:

- [HP P400 manual](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00572169/c00572169.pdf).
- [Blog guide](http://www.tricksguide.com/how-to-expand-array-extend-logical-drive-raid-hp-acu.html)

Comment: Was able to create two separate, logical drives as you stated, just wanted to confirm in case anyone has same question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The HP Smart Array P400 supports [up to 32 logical drives](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/productbulletin.html#spectype=worldwide&type=html&docid=12400).

Yes, it is possible to expand an array after it is created ([User Guide, p. 16](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00572169/c00572169.pdf)).

The P400i should be the same, as it is just a version of the P400 that is sold "integrated" with the system.